# When writer throw non skippable exception(i.e. StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) then processor going infinite loop

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Here is step configuration:

```
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step getKeysFromDB(@Value("#{jobParameters[name]}") String name) {
        
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("life-ins-core-thread-" + "data-");
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setTaskDecorator(new Slf4JTaskDecorator());
        
        return new StepBuilder("", jobRepository)
                .partitioner(STEP_GET_KEYS_FROM_SOURCE_DB, rangePartitioner)
                    .partitionHandler(null).step(processData())
                    .gridSize(1)
                    .taskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor)
                            .build();
    }
    
    
    private Step processData() {
        
        SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = new StepBuilder("slaveStep", jobRepository)
                .chunk(1, transactionManager);
        
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(preProcessingWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(postProcessingWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(batchDetailItemWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(postProcessingRWriter);
        
        simpleStepBuilder
                        .reader(sourceDbKeysReader)
                        .processor(stagingToBatchDetailProcessor)
                        .writer(sequenceWriterNeeded())
                        .listener(coreItemProcessorListener)
                        .listener(coreItemWriterListener)
                        .listener(new CoreChunkListener ())
                        .listener(coreStepExecutionListener);
                    
                        return simpleStepBuilder.faultTolerant()
                            .retryLimit(2)
                            .retry(BatchSystemException.class)
                            .skipLimit(2)
                            .skip(SkippableException.class)
                            .build();
    }
    
    private CompositeItemWriter sequenceWriterNeeded() {
        
        CompositeItemWriter compositeWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
        
        List<ItemWriter> listWriter = new ArrayList<>();
        listWriter.add(preProcessingWriter);
        listWriter.add(batchDetailItemWriter);
        listWriter.add(postProcessingWriter);
        listWriter.add(postProcessingRWriter);
                compositeWriter.setDelegates(listWriter);
        return compositeWriter;
        
    }
```

Here is my DataProcessor class

```
@Service
@StepScope
public class StagingToBatchDetailProcessor implements ItemProcessor<HashMap<String, Object>, HashMap<String, Object>>{
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StagingToBatchDetailProcessor.class);
    
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    public StagingToBatchDetailProcessor(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> process(HashMap<String, Object> item) throws Exception {
        logger.info("inside StagingToBatchDetailProcessor::process");
        
        
        item.put("last_output", "item2");
         return item;
    }

}
```

Just giving an example the same structure to understand the scenario.
if i see the code of **FaultTolerantChunkProcessor** only retryCallback is happening its not going in recoveryCallback.

```
    try {
                    batchRetryTemplate.execute(retryCallback, recoveryCallback,
                            new DefaultRetryState(inputs, rollbackClassifier));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    RetryContext context = contextHolder.get();
                    if (!batchRetryTemplate.canRetry(context)) {
                        /*
                         * BATCH-1761: we need advance warning of the scan about to start in
                         * the next transaction, so we can change the processing behaviour.
                         */
                        data.scanning(true);
                    }
                    throw e;
                }
```

it should throw ExhaustedRetryException :

```
if (!shouldSkip(itemWriteSkipPolicy, context.getLastThrowable(), -1)) {
                        throw new ExhaustedRetryException(
                                "Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.",
                                context.getLastThrowable());
                    }
```

This issue is getting resolved once in processData step by using processorNonTransactional();

```
private Step processData() {
        
        SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = new StepBuilder("slaveStep", jobRepository)
                .chunk(1, transactionManager);
        
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(preProcessingBeamWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(postProcessingBeamWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(batchDetailItemWriter);
        simpleStepBuilder.listener(postProcessingReconWriter);
        
        simpleStepBuilder
                        .reader(sourceDbKeysReader)
                        .processor(stagingToBatchDetailProcessor)
                        .writer(sequenceWriterNeeded())
                        .listener(coreItemProcessorListener)
                        .listener(coreItemWriterListener)
                        .listener(new CoreChunkListener ())
                        .listener(coreStepExecutionListener);
                    
                        return simpleStepBuilder.faultTolerant().**processorNonTransactional**()
                            .retryLimit(2)
                            .retry(BatchSystemException.class)
                            .skipLimit(2)
                            .skip(SkippableException.class)
                            .build();
    }
```

or by returning always new object without modifying inputItem in processor write method:

```
@Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> process(HashMap<String, Object> item) throws Exception {
        logger.info("inside StagingToBatchDetailProcessor::process");
        HashMap<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        obj.put("final_outpot", item.get("final_output"));
        
        item.put("last_output", "item2");
         return obj;
    }
```

this issue coming when we migration done spring boot 2.7.13 to spring boot 3.1.6. I have checked every thing but don't see any issue, Just wondering there two solution what makes difference **processorNonTransactional** or retuning **new Object from processor**. I don't want to go with both solution as how it will impact on without transaction and with new object may leads to out of memory issue. As data is related to payment need to processed.